# How do I insert a literal tab character?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I am editing a Makefile in XCode. How do I actually insert a tab character, ASCII value 9? If I press TAB, it inserts 4 spaces, and `make` complains because decades ago the creator of `make` had a handful of users and didn't want to change the program to not require literal tabs because it would break backwards compatibility or something.

Normally when editing a Makefile I just copy and paste an existing TAB character, but with a new clean one, I cannot do this.

Comment: If you're willing to restrict all users of your makefiles to always using GNU make 3.82 or newer, you can use the `.RECIPEPREFIX` variable to change the recipe prefix character to something else besides TAB.  Other than that you'll have to find yourself a real editor that can understand Makefile syntax.  AFAIK, Xcode cannot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Xcode 6.4, at least, you can enter a literal tab with Option-Tab. This seems to work regardless of the indentation settings.

Comment: Nice! How'd you figure that one out?

Comment: I don't remember exactly :-) . It was some combination of thinking there had to be some way to do this and also playing around with possible key combinations in case I had to make a custom keyboard shortcut.

Comment: For those interested, I now realize that this key combination is in the Xcode keybindings under "Insert Tab without Extra Action".

Comment: wow! I was grappling with inserting TAB in my makefile in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

You could just change your editing preference is Xcode to use tabs while editing a makefile

[image]

Easier than messing about moving to other editors and pasting literals.

Comment: Is there a way to set it so it only does this when editing Makefiles, without me having to change the preferences back and forth?

Comment: Not that I know of, unless you want to use something like Emacs or Vim.

Answer (score 2):

```
close the file in Xcode
open the file in TextEdit
be sure to check the "Ignore rich text commands" at the bottom of the open dialog
position the cursor at the beginning of a line and push TAB
close TextEdit
open the file in Xcode
select "Show Invisibles" from the "Editor" menu
note that ironically, the TABs are not displayed
however, spaces are displayed, which allows you to tell which lines start with tabs
copy the tab character as needed
```

If you ever meet that guy who that who thought that starting a line with a TAB was a good idea, slap him upside the back of the head, and slap him hard!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've taken to opening a TextEdit, placing a TAB there, then copying + pasting it into XCode.